# Mocking android applications like the contacts app using Mockito

Tags: android, mockito, functional-testing

I am trying to write functional tests for an android application. The problem is that most functional testing frameworks that I have explored (calabash-android, robotium) have a limitation on the number of activities from different applications that can be tested in the same test. So if in one workflow I need to select some contacts from the android contact picker I cant test that entire flow because the contact picker activity is part of the android contacts application and the framework can't test an activity from my application and the contacts application at the same time.

One possible solution my team thought of was to mock out the call to the contacts activity to return a dummy intent with contact information so that our application workflow can be tested. We are trying to use mockito to achieve this. However I am stuck pretty early on. Here is what I am trying to do

```
MyActivity mockActivity = mock(MyActivity.class);
when(mockActivity.startActivityForResult(<?>,anyInt())).thenReturn(fakeIntent);
```

I am not sure what to put in the first parameter in the second line. I have tried Intent.class and android.content.Intent.class however it throws a compile error. If anyone has worked with mocking activities using mockito, some help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. - If I understand correctly mocking is used more in unit testing than functional testing. So these tests would be more of a hybrid. If anyone has a better suggestion on how to go about these functional tests on android I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this without knowing the signature of your `startActivityForResult` method, but the general idea is to use `any(Xxx.class)`, where `Xxx` is the type of the parameter.  So either

```
when(mockActivity.startActivityForResult(any(Xxx.class),anyInt())).thenReturn(fakeIntent);
```

or the (kind of equivalent)

```
doReturn(fakeIntent).when(mockActivity).startActivityForResult(any(Xxx.class),anyInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cannot really "mock" (actually "spy") on the activity you're testing since it is created out of your control by Android's instrumentation code. In a unit-test environment where you would have control, you could follow the `mock(MyActivity.class)` or `spy(myActivityInstance)` path (spy would actually be better because you could re-use most of the activity's original implementation), but here not.

The only solution I found for this dilemma was to move certain functionality out of the activity into utility classes, ideally utilizing [roboguice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice) for that (`@ContextSingleton`s can be used to process activity results). Then, in your test project, you would create your own test guice injector, set that as base application injector before you call `getActivity()` for the first time and then let the activity work on your mocked utility class.

[I outlined the complete process here.](http://www.thomaskeller.biz/blog/2012/10/18/runtime-replace-implementations-with-roboguice-in-functional-tests/)